# How to Print Word Documents Using uiprintinteractioncontroller class

Tags: ios, printing

Need some help.
I am able to print pdf & images directly 
but need to print document pr ppt files.
Please help me out 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have used NSMutableData *pdfData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:aPrintData];
 UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, kPDFPageBounds, nil);
 UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
 UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 UIGraphicsEndPDFContext(); to convert plain text to pdf but which not work for document or ppt or other formats.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You don't need to convert any format to PDF before printing. Simply set the printing data & present the menu.

```
[UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController].printingItem = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.url]; //url of your word doc

[[UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController] presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:nil];
```